# Some applications are broken after installing gnome-shell-extensions

Tags: 20.04, gnome, software-center, gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension

Some of my apps have *lost their icons*, and they *won't start* when I left-click them. That is, nothing happened, or, nothing appeared in the top left corner screen, besides the "Activities" button. [Interface of the "Show Applications" button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z5U3B.jpg)

Those apps have also *disappeared* in `/usr/share/applications`, `~/.local/share/applications`, as  well as in `/usr/bin`. That is, I can't find "Visual Studio Code" when I run `ls /usr/bin | grep code`, as opposed to when I find Google Chrome with `ls /usr/bin | grep chrome` and that would give me `google-chrome`,...

Furthermore, when I search for those apps in *the software center* it says they are installed yet nothing happens when I press *"Launch"*, besides *their icons* in the software center are also lost. [Interface of "Visual Studio Code" in Software Center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIXrq.png)

I think the problem was when I tried to install `gnome-shell-extensions` with `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions` to use some of my favorite gnome shell extensions. Though afterward, my favorite extensions work, this issue comes.

Comment: Are all of these snap applications? You can see installed snap applications with the command `snap list`. For sure, the cause is not the installation of the gnome-shell-extensions package.

Comment: wow, they are! `snap list`  shows that except for the `core` snap package, all the others have `broken` in *Notes*. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I had to **enable `apparmor` at boot** before-hand by:

1. Append `apparmor=1` and `security=apparmor` to the file `/etc/default/grub`.
2. `sudo update-grub`
3. `sudo reboot`

Then **remove and install those broken packages again** with this script:

```
#!/bin/sh

tofix="`snap list | awk '/broken/{print $1}'`"

for s in $tofix; do
        sudo snap remove "$s"
        sudo snap install "$s"
done
```

p/s thanks to vanadium that I know where I should start fixing my problem.